# "kill %1" fails and prints "No such process" inside script

Tags: shell, kill, dash-shell

I am currently using dash as main shell.
I tried to write a little function that should imitate wait, but with some text.

Here's a minimal, working code:

```
#!/bin/dash

wait() {
  echo Waiting...
  local pid="${1}"; shift
  local delay=.250
  while kill -0 "${pid}" 2>/dev/null; do
    echo Still waiting...
    sleep "${delay}"
  done
  echo Resuming
}

main() {
  sleep 3 &
  wait %1
}

main
```

If you copy-paste it in a dash shell you can see the code works just fine.
Anyway, if you try to save it in a file, it does not.

After some troubleshooting I've done I found out that deleting `2>/dev/null`, you can see an error message: `kill: No such process`, *but* using `command wait "${pid}"` it just waits for it.

So for example:

```
#!/bin/dash

wait() {
  echo Waiting...
  local pid="${1}"; shift
  command wait "${pid}"
  echo Resuming
}

main() {
  sleep 3 &
  wait %1
}

main
```

works fine as a file script, too.

I am not sure where/what I am wrong in this piece of code and some things I tried didn't help.

Among the trials I tried to convert `%1` to its pid, but `jobs -p %1` in a subshell (such as `var="$(jobs -p %1)"`) fails badly.

Any tip?

Comment: Instead of a jobspec like %1, use an actual PID (`wait $!`) and it'll work even with shells compiled without interactive extensions.

Comment: @Charles are there any caveats of enabling job controls for a non-interactive shell?

Comment: @oguzismail, only shells with the optional user portability utilities extension to the baseline POSIX standard support job control at all. I could definitely conceive of a small busybox build or such not containing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) is disabled in non-interactive shells. Enable it with `set -m`, or by appending `-m` to the shebang, and it'll work.

Example:

```
$ dash -c 'sleep 1 & kill %1 && echo success'
dash: 1: kill: No such process

$ dash -m -c 'sleep 1 & kill %1 && echo success'
success
```